# Is there a fade + disable plugin in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

So we commonly come across faded objects that cannot be used on the Internet, such as a text-box that has a gray/faded appearance that cannot be clicked in and typed into.

I would like to do the same with a CSS object, which would later be un-faded and enabled to be used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a fade + disable plugin in jQuery?

#### jQuery plugin

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fadeAndDisable = function(delay) {
        delay = delay || 500;
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(0.5, delay, function() {
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            })
        });
    }

    $.fn.fadeAndEnable = function(delay) {
        delay = delay || 500;
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(1, delay, function() {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            })
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/uCYws/).

#### Usage

```
$('input').fadeAndDisable(1000);
$('input').fadeAndEnable(1000);
```

You may want to extend this to allow callbacks, which is trivial to add.

Comment: Hm it doesn't fade or disable in my case. >< I'm trying to prevent a div container from accepting dragged in objects + be faded until I allow it to. The container unfortunately isn't disabled/faded.

Comment: @honeymind You may have implemented it wrong or something is clashing with it.

Comment: What I needed what the .droppable( 'disable' ) method. =]

Answer (score 6):

You mean something like:

```
$(element).fadeTo('fast', 0.5).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Note that this assumes jQuery.

Comment: Eh it doesn't quite disable it in my case but thank you. ^^ In my situation, I am still able to drag-and-drop objects into the container.

Comment: Ahh, I'm honestly not sure if there's a way to disable drag-and-drop, but since that's a piece of jQuery functionality instead of core HTML functionality it would have to be within that scope. But I would assume you could programmatically unbind the events when you wanted it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [fadeout()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and then you can include option to disable..